# Close all popup dialogs when main window closed in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows

In my web application a lot of popups opened from the parent window using 'window.open'. So I want to close all those popups when my application's main window is closed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit problematic to know that the user closes the window but assuming you do achieve that (by a close button or subscribing to the beforeUnload event) you can close the opened windows by following the next bullets:

1. When opening a window, save its
   object which is returned from the
   `window.open` method (preferably to an
   array so you have all objects in a
   central place).
2. When you find out the main window is
   closing, execute the `close` method
   on the saved window objects.

Another possibility:

1. Use timer on the opened windows to
   check if `opener` is defined (you
   can try to use `typeof` on a method in
   the opener page).
2. When you find out the opener doesn't
   exist, close the window.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `callback` that will notify you that the user closed his browser.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible! You cannot catch browser close event.

You can use model popups to be sure user closed popups before closing the main window.

Comment: How can one create a modal popup with javascript/ HTML in order to force the pop-up to be closed?